# Caliburn Micro - Text in TextBox wont display

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am working my way through an old Caliburn Micro tutorial ([here](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/)). I am up to part 2 ([here](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/1/16/caliburn-micro-part-2-data-binding-and-events/)). I've managed to update the App.xaml and AppBootstrapper.cs to be compatible with 3.0.3 and WPF (as outlined under the section 'WPF' on the 'Documentation' page here). I am using VS 2013.

The tutorial shows the app having the value '50' appearing after initialization. My app just shows this:

[image]

Here is the code so far:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CaliburnMicroApp"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class=" CaliburnMicroApp.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**AppViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnMicroApp.ViewModels
{
    class AppViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private int _count = 50;

        private int Count
        {
            get { return _count; }
            set
            {
                _count = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Count);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanIncrementCount);
            }
        }

        public void IncrementCount()
        {
            Count++;
        }

        public bool CanIncrementCount
        {
            get { return Count < 100; }
        }
    }
}
```

**AppView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnMicroApp.Views.AppView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Grid Width="300" Height="300" Background="LightBlue">
        <RepeatButton Name="IncrementCount" Content="Up" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Name="Count" Margin="20" FontSize="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**AppBootstrapper.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using CaliburnMicroApp.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;


namespace CaliburnMicroApp
{
    public class AppBootstrapper : Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase
    {
        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<AppViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your Count property in your AppViewModel to public.

Comment: Eheh, no problem. Sometimes those are the errors we stuck as developers ;)